# Looking to loop two VBA macros together in Excel, but I think I'm just missing something very small

Tags: vba, excel

OK, so I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this right, but I feel as if the answer should be very straightforward!

First, I have two macros written, we'll call these LeftCut and RightCut. These will cut out a row of four columns and paste them elsewhere in the sheet. The VBA code for these is

```
    Sub RightCut()
ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-1]).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)).Cut
ActiveCell.Offset([0], [6]).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-6]).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub

   Sub LeftCut
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Cut
ActiveCell.Offset([0], [10]).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-10]).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Both of these work by themselves. Now, all I want to do is loop these together so if a certain condition is met, say, if the four left columns don't match the four right columns and one row needs to be cut out, then one of these two macros are called.

Now, I have a pseudo code written for a Do While loop, but is this even close to what I'm looking for? The main problem will be that at some points in the worksheet, up to twenty of the rows need to be cut and paste, so I want the macros above to be used over and over until ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1). Is this possible with a Do While loop??

```
Sub HighAce()


Dim i As Long
Dim ActiveCell As Range

i = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Do While i <= 40043

     Set ActiveCell = Range("E" & i)

    If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-1]) Then
     ActiveCell.Offset([1], [0]).Select

    ElseIf ActiveCell > ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-1]) Then
      Application.Run "'Methylation Array.xlsm'!NewBlueCut"

    ElseIf ActiveCell < ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-1]) Then
     Application.Run "'Methylation Array.xlsm'!NewBlueCut"

    Else: Stop

    End If

Loop


 End Sub
```

Am I on the right track here? Is there a line I'm missing?

I appreciate any help anyone can provide. I'll come back to this problem later with a fresh mind, and I'll see if I can find a solution myself too!

Thanks!

EDIT: Sample dataset

x x x A01 A01 x x x

x x x A02 A04 x x x

x x x A06 A05 x x x

x x x A07 A06 x x x

x x x A08 A09 x x x

So if the A01 on the top right is the active cell, when ActiveCell=ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1) then move onto the next row. Here, since the Active Cell is > the adjacent cell, carry out Leftcut. Now, the Activecell < the Adjacent cell, so carry out RightCut. Another rightcut will make these two cells equal, so the cursor will move to the next row, and go again.

Comment: You should iterate OR simply increase `i` inside loop, otherwise it'll be endless.

Comment: Can you show us sample data structure? I feel certain you won't need to macros for this...

Comment: I'd like to answer this but like Peter Albert said, I am unsure what the purpose is. It looks like you have two sets of four columns and want to go down the line making them match each other on each row? Can you confirm this and maybe elaborate? Also, your dataset description is a little off I think. If your active cell were the top left A01 then comparing it to the cell to its right would need .Offset(0,1) not .Offset(0,-1) (correct me if I'm wrong). Your description actually made me more confused.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I was mistaken there. Sorry, activecell is the one on the RIGHT. So, I have two sets of four columns, with thousands of rows. All I want to do is line up the rows with matching D and E cells by removing the rows thats don't belong. I want to cut and paste these elsewhere. So, in the example above, there is no A02, so I'd cut out that set. There is no A04 or A05, so I'd cut out those sets, but A06 and A06 match, so I'd move onto the next row from there and carry on. 

Does this make more sense? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

As Peter L. mentioned, you should at least increase `i` in your loop.

However, I'd recommend you better familiarize yourself a bit more with `.Offset` and `.Resize` of ranges. This will allow you to reduce your code significantly.

I'd use the following construct for the loop:

```
Set rng = Range("E2")
While _condition_
    ...Do something
    Set rng = rng.offset(1)
Wend
```

I end up with this final code, also reworking your cut subs:

```
Sub RightCut(rng As Range)
    rng.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 4).Cut
    rng.Offset(, 5).Resize(, 4).Insert xlDown
    rng.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 4).Delete xlUp
End Sub


Sub LeftCut(rng As Range)
    rng.Resize(, 4).Cut
    rng.Offset(, 10).Resize(, 4).Insert xlDown
    rng.Resize(, 4).Delete xlUp
End Sub

Sub HighAce()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lngcount as Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set rng = Range("E2")

    While rng <> "" And rng <> rng.Offset(, -1)
        lngCount = lngCount + 1
        If lngCount > 40000 Then Stop
        If rng > rng.Offset(, -1) Then
            LeftCut rng
        ElseIf rng < rng.Offset(, -1) Then
            RightCut rng
        Else
            lngCount = 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
        End If

        'This assign the next row

    Wend
 End Sub
```

I have not tested it as I don't have the data and don't understand the purpose, but I'm sure it'll give you a starting point!

Comment: Great, thanks! Now I have a starting point. Although I haven't gotten your codes working yet, I'm just taking the time to decipher the steps. Can you tell me what setting the dim as rng does? And why are you putting rng into the arguments of the two subs? 

Thanks!

Comment: `Dim rng as Range` tells the VBA interpreter that the variable rng is a Range object. Among others, it allows one to use IntelliSense every time one type `rng.`, i.e. one sees all methods and properties of the range class.

Comment: I put rng in the arguments of the two sub, as I'm avoiding the use of `ActiveCell` (which is kind of a hidden way to pass an argument, namely a certain cell). Selecting/activating cells is slower - and much harder to understand in VBA code.

Comment: PS: Once you figure everything out, don't forget to accept the answer! :-)

Comment: Great. I'm still getting my head around it, and experimenting. I won't forget to accept it though! ;)

Comment: Ok, so I'm having one or two problems with this approach. With the loop above, the cycle moves down to the next row after it carries out one of the Cuts. So, if I have six rows of cells that need to be cut out, the macro will only work on every other one. 

Should the code be moving to the next row after a RightCut, even if it doesn't cause the two middle cells to be equal?

Comment: You are right. As I stated, I did not fully understand the logic you need to implement. Let me adopt the code...

Comment: Also, When the two middle cells are equal, instead of ending the code, I want to move the selected cell one row down. However, when I add in the line:

     {{ElseIf rng = rng.Offset(, -1) Then
                rng.Offset(1, 0).Select}} 

it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: check out the updated code. still not sure it'll work fully, but give you another idea. I added a counter a "safeguard" in case somehow you end up in an endless loop. Adopt code as required...

Comment: I think we're getting closer... Just now the RightCut isn't working properly, as it's stopping and throwing back an Object Required error before pasting the cell contents. 

Everything else seems fine, but when the middle cells are matched, the code just stops instead of moving one row down.

Comment: sorry, need to log off now. Try to debug by stepping through the code with F9 and looking at the contents of the variables with the Locals window (View-Locals)

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help though. I'll let you know if I succeed!